# How method POST faster in FLASK and redirect

Tags: python, flask

I try to make one micro server,

```
@serv.route('/booking', methods=['POST'])
def booking():
    Do job A
    Do job B
    etc...
    return redirect('/direct_site')
```

if Job A, Job B connect to google API, my server have to do A, B first, after that do Redirect.
So how to make it faster, example.

```
@serv.route('/booking', methods=['POST'])
def booking():
    redirect('/direct_site')
    
    
    return Do job A, do job C, etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- Redirect first, then do the jobs.

  The main issue here is that once you do the redirect, you lose the
  channel to the user. That means that if job A or job B has some sort
  of error (or, indeed, success), you will no longer be able to
  directly display it to the user; you will instead need to track it
  elsewhere, and if necessary display it to the user later (or to
  yourself as the site admin).

  With that in mind, the new code will probably look something like this:

  ```
  @serv.route('/booking', methods=['POST'])
  def booking():
      put job A on the queue
      put job B on the queue
      return redirect('/direct_site')
  ```

  Elsewhere, you'll have something handling the queue (which may be in memory, database or a dedicated queueing system), other pages for the user and/or yourself to check on the status of jobs, etc. It will no longer really be "micro"...
- Do the jobs in parallel, then redirect.

  This will be a lot simpler, but the redirect will still need to wait for the longest of the jobs to complete. You will be able to collect the results before redirecting the user, which means you'll be able to report any errors directly and only redirect the user to the "success" page if the jobs were, in fact, successful.

  There are a number of ways to do the jobs in parallel (threads, futures, async). Which one you choose depends on what you're using elsewhere in the code and/or familiar with, and what sort of work is done in the jobs. If they're mostly API calls across the network, with little processing on your end, any of them will do the job. Futures will be easiest if each job is a single API call, threads if some of the jobs involve multiple API calls which depend on each other.

Comment: thank you, job A give value to redirect, so another job i try to. do job A first, redirect, do job B, do job C, do job etc...

Comment: Right, that's basically the first option; do job A first, then everything else is pushed on a queue (which may just be the "bookings" table in the database, with fields indicating the jobs that are still to be done / retried / reported as successful or failed).

Comment: Thank you, i have another question, when waiting for site redicrect, if customer have no patient, they well reload browers, then my server will re-run the Job A? How to solve it?

Comment: That really depends on what Job A does. Can you make it idempotent somehow, so it can be run multiple times without causing any harm?

Comment: Job A make a event in Google Calendar and return the Event ID, link event.